# Uploading Excel file using tkinter and processing it as a dataframe with complete user interaction with gui

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have designed a simple GUI with tkinter. I am uploading an excel file from desktop and with the help of path of this file, I am trying to process this excel file as a dataframe. I am using `filedialog.askopenfilename()` for uploading the file. I have design a menubar `file` and its submenu as `open` for uploading the file.

Following is the code to achieve it

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu= menubar)
subMenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
def browse_file():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu =subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=browse_file)
root.geometry("600x600")
root.mainloop()
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
.
. #Further processing of all three dataframe .
.
print(df)
```

I want to upload three different Excel files by this way and processing dataframes.Above code is only for uploading of one dataframe as an example. Above code works fine for it but processing of dataframe starts when I close the gui after uploading the file.
I want to know, how I can upload this file with processing of file starts simultaneously while GUI remains open?
Because I have to close my GUI to start further processing of dataframe

Also if I am writing

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
.
. #Further processing of all three dataframe .
.
print(df)
```

above `root.mainloop` than I am getting following error-

```
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

But I have defined filename as global variable. I am trying above code so that file will process while gui remains open. Why I am getting this error?

So my question is how to upload all the three excel files and processing it as dataframe while gui remains open. Because I have to close the GUI to make further processing. I want to make this GUI as more interactive with user. If I am uploading a file a status of uploading file appears.

Comment: The short answer is to move `df = pd.read_excel(filename)` inside your function `browse_file`.

Comment: Yes I have tried it. It works.But I have to do very long processing to three different datframes. Will it work ? Or would it be simpler while writing hundreds of line of code and bind that code inside def browse_file():

Comment: Try initialising ```filename``` variable in the main code before the function call like ```filename = ''```.

Comment: If its long processing, it will freeze your GUI until the processing is done. You can consider `threading` your whole process.

Comment: @pavel it is giving     with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' if I am initializing filename = ""

Comment: @Henry Yik than how to achieve the desired task.Can you please suggest some simple way to  achieve it?

Comment: @Alexander Cécile It is receiving file inside browse_file() method but still shows file not found error. I have try to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

At minimum it could be something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
from threading import Thread

root = tk.Tk()
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu= menubar)
subMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

def browse_file():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    #whatever you need to do with your df...

menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=lambda: Thread(target=browse_file).start())

root.geometry("600x600")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will try it in my code. It means I have to use Threads for achieving the desired result. Is it true?

Comment: If you want to prevent your GUI from freezing, yes.

Comment: But I have inter-dependency among dataframes. So  I cannot achieve it using threading

Comment: Can you please provide any other way?

Comment: I don't really understand your requirement. If you need to process all 3 dataframes, then you should have your user select 3 files first instead of just selecting one.

Comment: Yes. I have design separate submenus to upload three excel files. But these excel files have inter-dependencies  in order to generate a final dataframe

Comment: @VishavGupta I will echo Henri Yik’s comment, _I don’t really understand your requirements._